# Upgrading Borderlands 2 to Borderlands 2: Game of the Year edition for DLCs

Tags: borderlands-2

I want to buy Borderlands 2 Game Of The Year edition. I however have Borderlands 2 already and don't want to buy the season pass. Will this affect anything because all I want is all the DLC's but the season pass costs more.

Comment: One thing : G2A is baaaaaaad.

Comment: Why do you think its bad? Its the first time for me to try it out. So before I buy can you tell me why is bad and why I shouldn't use it? Thanks.

Comment: Well, it sells digital keys which provenance is not always clear. Actually, buying from this kind of sites is just giving money to the wrong people.

Comment: I'm not judging you. I just think that not paying at all is better than buying from thieves. Of course, now I can afford my games I buy them :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GOTY version will overwrite your base game and add all the DLC it includes. It doesn't include *all* the released DLC, so keep that in mind.
Your will be able to continue playing your saved characters through the new content without losing anything.

**The Borderlands 2 Game of the Year pack comes with:**

- Borderlands 2 the full game (you **don't** get a 2nd copy if you already own it)
- Mr. Torgue’s Campaign of Carnage
- Tiny Tina’s Assault on Dragon Keep
- Captain Scarlet and her Pirate Booty
- Sir Hammerlock’s Big Game Hunt
- Ultimate Vault Hunter’s Upgrade Pack 1
- The Mechromaner Character Pack
- The Psycho Character Pack
- The Creature Slaughterdome
- Collector’s Edition Pack

Answer (score 1):

If by changing anything, you mean for the saves or your profile, it won't change anything. If the steam key given by a third-party key reseller works, since you already have Borderlands 2, it will only add the DLC to your games.